# Gemfile ROR version and local machine ROR version mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am a complete beginner to ROR and heroku. Currently I am trying to create an app with a git from bitbucket and my gemfile version (2.2.3) is different from my ruby on rails version of 2.3.1.

What are the steps I can take to ensure that my gemfile can be changed?

This mismatch in gemfile caused my "git push heroku master" to fail with the following errors.

**An error occurred while installing mime-types (3.0), and Bundler cannot
remote:continue.**

Thank you so much! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 2.3 is kind of cool - stuff like the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), so I recommend installing it, but if you don't want to -

In either your Gemfile or `.ruby-version` file, you'll probably have a line which says `ruby 2.3.1`. Temporarily change this to your installed version, 2.2.3.

The run `bundle`, or perhaps `bundle --without production` if you want to skip the gems marked as belonging to the `production` group only. For example, if you don't have postgres installed locally.

Then switch back your Gemfile or `.ruby-version` to 2.3.1. Commit and try and push.

What does this accomplish? It keeps the ruby version pinned at 2.3 for heroku, but installs a `Gemfile.lock` using your installed version. Heroku requires a `Gemfile.lock` for development gems only, as far as I'm aware.

By the way, I'm assuming you're using **ruby** version 2.2.3 and not that **Rails** version. The current Rails version is 4.x.x or 5.x.x. To run Rails 2.x.x, you'll probably need to downgrade to Ruby 1.8.7 or something.